# D-Link wireless network usb will not auto-reconnect

Tags: wireless, usb

D-Link wireless network usb will not auto-reconnect. I'm connecting to a dual band linksys router... the windows computers disconnect also, but they auto-reconnect... 
So, I'm wondering... is there a program to auto-reconnect to the router???

Comment: what is the output of `lsusb` ?so we can know the exact model of dlink you are using

Comment: if the output says 2001:330d for your device, see here https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu this is a better driver for that device

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you follow [this tutorial](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/277-ubuntu-precise-dwa-131-rev-b1).

First thing is to check that your key is the right one.

Run `lsusb` and if the output includes `Bus 002 Device 020: ID 2001:330d D-Link Corp` this tutorial will work.

Now install the firmware `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware linux-firmware-nonfree`

Next manually load it with these commands:

`sudo modprobe rtl8192cu swenc=1`

`echo "2001 330D" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id`

The blue light should switch on. It can be used from Network Manager.

To get it to auto load at boot:

`sudo gedit /etc/modules`

and add the lines:

```
# DWA-131 rev B1 D-Link WiFi
rtl8192cu
```

then

`sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/net-rtl8192cu.conf`

and add the lines

```
#D-Link WiFi
options rtl8192cu swenc=1
```

Finally,

`sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

and add the following lines before the `exit 0`

```
# Declare DWA-131 USB ID to rtl8192cu module D-Link WiFi
echo "2001 330D" | tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id
```

You can now reboot your computer. WiFi connection should start automatically ...